# Java call to create new Area doesn't create shape?

Tags: java, paintcomponent, area

I was working on an issue where I was getting a cast problem trying to cast from Shape to Area (see previous post [cast exception question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614244/java-class-cast-exception-java-awt-geom-path2d-double)). Now it seems that my shape that is create is not getting created correctly. Instead of posting all of my source code here I am attaching a link to all the source files [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_Uf4KgCMRKORWpVc1dpcUdVcFE&usp=sharing).

Essentially I create the shape as follows with a standard call of

```
YingYang shape = new YingYang();
shape = shape.moveTo(x, y);
shape = shape.scaleBy(size);
shape.setColor(getNextColor());
```

and the calls to the Area Class are:

```
public YingYang()
{
    Area mainCircle = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(...)
    ...
    yingYang.add(mainCircle);
}
```

The MoveTo call:

```
public YingYang moveTo(double x, double y)
{  

    at.translate(x, y);
    at.setToTranslation(x, y);
    yingYang.transform(at);
    return new YingYang(at.createTransformedShape(yingYang));
}
```

The ScaleBy:

```
public YingYang scaleBy(double scale)
{
    double cx = this.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
    double cy = this.getBounds2D().getCenterY();

    at.translate(cx, cy);
    at.setToTranslation(cx, cy);
    at.scale(scale, scale);      
    at.translate(-cx, -cy);
    return new YingYang(at.createTransformedShape(yingYang));
}
```

When I call the paintComponent() in my drawing panel:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
    for(YingYang s : shapes)
    {       
        System.out.println(s.getBounds2D());
        g2.setColor(s.getColor());
        g2.fill(s);
    }
}
```

The print statement prints out:

```
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=0.0,y=0.0,w=0.0,h=0.0]
```

I'm at a loss... Any Ideas?

Comment: I see YingYang extends Area but also contains a field called yingYang that is also an Area object. Are you meaning to getBounds2D on the field? Maybe I am missing something since I really just skimmed the code but it seems a little redundant to extend a class and then mainly be using a field that is of the superclass. Either way maybe what you mean to do is override getBounds2D in YingYang so it returns yingYang.getBounds2D?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have combined both my recommendations into one piece of code. If you are going to use your variable yingYang then you should implement the shape on the class. However if you are going to extend the area you need to remove the yingYang variable and use the class as the area eg: yingYang.add(mainCircle); becomes add(mainCircle);... essentially remove all references of the yingYang variable.

So instead of the "yingYang" variable you are using "this". heres is a modified version of your YingYang class with the references removed.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class YingYang extends Area
{
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    private boolean movingRight = true;
    private boolean movingUp = true;
    private Color color = Color.BLACK;
    private int dx = 10, dy = 10;

    public YingYang(Shape shape)
    {
        super(shape);
    }


    public YingYang()
    {

        // Construct the Outer Circle & Lower Dot
        Area mainCircle = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(-210, -210, 420, 420));
        Area lowerDot = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(-10, 90, 40, 40));
        mainCircle.subtract(lowerDot);

        // Begin Construction of the whit side of symbol
        Area whiteSide = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(-200, -200, 400, 400));
        Area rect = new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, -200, 200, 400));
        whiteSide.subtract(rect);

        // Construct the upper white Circle
        Area upperCircle = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(-100, -200, 200, 200));
        whiteSide.add(upperCircle);

        // Construct the Upper Dot
        Area upperDot = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(-10, -110, 40, 40));
        whiteSide.subtract(upperDot);

        // Remove the lower circle portion
        Area lowerCircle = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(-100, 0, 200, 200));
        whiteSide.subtract(lowerCircle);


        // Add Main Circle
        add(mainCircle);
        // Subtract the white side
        subtract(whiteSide);

    }

    //------------------------ Methods -----------------------------------------

    /**
     * Sets this shapes color
     * (must call getColor before drawing this shape)
     * @param color
     */
    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**
     * Gets this shapes current color
     * @return color
     */
    public Color getColor()
    {
        return this.color;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the shape is moving left to right
     * @return - boolean
     */
    public boolean isMovingRight()
    {
        return movingRight;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the shape is moving from down to up
     * @return - boolean
     */
    public boolean isMovingUp()
    {
        return movingUp;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the Horizontal Path that this shape is traveling
     */
    public void changeHorizonalMovement()
    {
        if(isMovingRight())
        {
            movingRight = false;
        }
        else
        {
            movingRight = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Changes the Vertical Path that this shape is traveling
     */
    public void changeVerticalMovement()
    {
        if(isMovingUp())
        {
            movingUp = false;
        }
        else
        {
            movingUp = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the direction of the Horizontal Path of this shape
     *  true = left to right : false = right to left
     * @param dir - boolean
     */
    public void setHorizonalMovement(boolean dir)
    {
        this.movingRight = dir;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the direction of the Vertical Path of this shape
     *  true = down to up : false = up to down
     * @param dir - boolean
     */
    public void setVerticalMovement(boolean dir){
        this.movingUp = dir;
    }

    /**
     * Moves the current shape by the amount x,y
     * @param x - double
     * @param y - double
     */
    public YingYang moveTo(double x, double y)
    {  

        at.translate(x, y);
        at.setToTranslation(x, y);
        transform(at);
        return new YingYang(at.createTransformedShape(this));
    }

    /**
     * Rotate this shape
     * @param theta - amount to rotate shape by
     * @return 
     */
    public YingYang rotate(double theta)
    {
        double cx = getBounds2D().getCenterX();
        double cy = getBounds2D().getCenterY();

        at.translate(cx, cy);
        at.setToTranslation(cx, cy);
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(theta));
        at.translate(-cx, -cy);
        return new YingYang(at.createTransformedShape(this));
    }

    public YingYang moveToAndRotate(double x, double y, double theta)
    {
        double cx = getBounds2D().getCenterX();
        double cy = getBounds2D().getCenterY();

        at.translate(cx, cy);
        at.setToTranslation(cx, cy);
        at.translate(x, y);
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(theta));
        at.translate(-cx, -cy);
        return new YingYang(at.createTransformedShape(this));
    }

    /**
     * Scales this shape uniformly by the amount of scale
     *   about the origin
     * @param scale - double
     */
    public YingYang scaleBy(double scale)
    {
        double cx = this.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
        double cy = this.getBounds2D().getCenterY();

        at.translate(cx, cy);
        at.setToTranslation(cx, cy);
        at.scale(scale, scale);      
        at.translate(-cx, -cy);
        return new YingYang(at.createTransformedShape(this));
    }

    /**
     * Rotates this shape theta degrees about the origin
     */
    public YingYang rotate(Double theta)
    {
        double cx = this.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
        double cy = this.getBounds2D().getCenterY();

        at.translate(cx, cy);
        at.setToTranslation(cx, cy);
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(theta));      
        at.translate(-cx, -cy);
        return new YingYang(at.createTransformedShape(this));
    }

    public int getDx()
    {
        return this.dx;
    }

    public void setDx(int x)
    {
        this.dx = x;
    }

    public int getDy()
    {
        return this.dy;
    }

    public void setDy(int y)
    {
        this.dy = y;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works more like it should from the standpoint of how to extend the Area. Not sure if this will fly for the assignment since we were give instructions to extend the shape class but yet the shape is made up of an Area of constructive geometry. I'll mark this as complete because it gives great insight in how to extend a class.  But while it corrected fundamental flaws in my code it opened others such as not getting it to update in the draw panel. I'll update the code in the shared folder if you can take a look and point me in the right direction.

Comment: @jbolt We can discuss the details in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java